# MongoDB slow to query 1M data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, query-optimization

1st of all sorry for my english.

For now my project have 1 million chat record.
So I want to query `Chats` collection from mongodb but It's take time to query and some time take 100% of cpu. So I want to know how to optimize query.

After I research maybe It should use `index` and `lean()` but I'm not clear how to using this with my data.

Here my `Chat` data look like

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("602c53cad1dc22359729bb62"),
    "textMessage" : "1",
    "imageNames" : [],
    "uuid" : "a9y10mfqtokl8mtk0l",
    "sendBy" : "a9y10m9s2skkwu564g",
    "sendTo" : "a9y10m9s2skkwvo7xl",
    "createDateTimestamp" : 1613517770901.0,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here my query function

```js
  Promise.all([
    UserModel.findOne({ uuid: selfUuid }).lean(),
    UserModel.findOne({ uuid: chatWithUuid }).lean(),
    Chat.find({
      $or: [
        { sendBy: uuid, sendTo: chatWithUuid },
        { sendBy: chatWithUuid, sendTo: uuid },
      ],
    })
      .lean()
      .sort({ createDateTimestamp: -1 })
  ]).then((result) => {
    const selfUser = result[0]
    const chatWithUser = result[1]
    const chatMessages = result[2]
    const responseData = chatMessages.map(({ sendBy, sendTo, ...props }) => {
      if (sendTo === selfUser.uuid) {
        return {
          ...props,
          sendTo: selfUser,
          sendBy: chatWithUser,
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...props,
          sendTo: chatWithUser,
          sendBy: selfUser,
        }
      }
    })
    response.success(res, responseData)
  }).catch((e) => {
    response.fail(res, e, 'fail to getSingleChat')
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query function and model  you can create following two indexes to speed up your searches:

```
1) {uuid:1}
2) {sendBy:1,sendTo:1}
```

Comment: Thank you :) after testing that reduce query time from 0.7 sec to 0.003 sec

Answer (score 1):

If you give index to collection for **createDateTimestamp** in mongodb. You don't need *.sort({ createDateTimestamp: -1 })* anymore.

Comment: use mean this `db.chats.createIndex({ createDateTimestamp: -1 })` ?

Comment: Yes, you can find more detail to [create index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) .
If you do that, you will save considerable time.